# Oracle: find all users with a particular privilege

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running as the sys user in the database and I would like to look for all the users who are granted with the CREATE ANY JOB privilege directly and indirectly.

I know dba_sys_privs can find those directly granted privilege but how about the indirect one? For examples, a user's privilege is granted by a role and even the role granted by another role.

Answer (score 0):

As [René Nyffenegger](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/recursively_list_privilege.html) nicely says:

```
SQL> set pagesize 100
SQL> set ver off
SQL>
SQL> select
  2    lpad(' ', 2*level) || c "Privilege, Roles and Users"
  3  from
  4    (
  5    /* THE PRIVILEGES */
  6      select
  7        null   p,
  8        name   c
  9      from
 10        system_privilege_map
 11      where
 12        name like upper('%&enter_privliege%')
 13    /* THE ROLES TO ROLES RELATIONS */
 14    union
 15      select
 16        granted_role  p,
 17        grantee       c
 18      from
 19        dba_role_privs
 20    /* THE ROLES TO PRIVILEGE RELATIONS */
 21    union
 22      select
 23        privilege     p,
 24        grantee       c
 25      from
 26        dba_sys_privs
 27    )
 28  start with p is null
 29  connect by p = prior c;
Enter value for enter_privliege: ALTER ANY TABLE

Privilege, Roles and Users
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ALTER ANY TABLE
    DBA
      SYS
      SYSTEM
    IMP_FULL_DATABASE
      DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE
        DBA
          SYS
          SYSTEM
        SYS
      DBA
        SYS
        SYSTEM
      SYS
    MDSYS
    SYS
    WMSYS

17 rows selected.

SQL>
```